# include_str! return an empty string if the specified file is not found

Tags: rust, macros

Is there a way for `include_str!` to default to an empty string if the file that it is looking for does not exist?

For example, if my directory looked like this:

```
main.rs
file.txt
```

And my code is:

```rs
fn main() {
  let file_contents = maybe_include_str!("file.txt"); // "hello world"
  let empty_contents = maybe_include_str!("nonexistent_file.txt"); // ""
}
```

Is there a way to do this using macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built in, I don't think so, but there is crate `include_optional`’s [`include_str_optional!`](https://docs.rs/include_optional/latest/include_optional/macro.include_str_optional.html) macro which does almost exactly this (it returns an `Option<&str>` instead of `&str`, but that's easily rectified).

```rust
let empty_contents = include_str_optional!("nonexistent_file.txt").unwrap_or_default();
```